# Change gender of voice

Tags: voice-manipulation

I'm looking to change the gender of a voice, man to woman and vice versa, preferably on linux. I can change the pitch, but it mostly makes the audio just sound chipmunky.

What are the other things that make a voice gender specific? How can I change them?

I have tried soundtouch, sox and LADSPA/Autotalent. Like I said, the main problem is the high pitch for a man->woman just sounds chipmunky. Anyone have success with this before?

I'm looking to add this into Freeswitch, so a C API is preferable, but I can fallback to a pipe.

Comment: You're looking to change the *formant* of a voice. Here's a link to how to do it in Audacity: http://audacity.wonderhowto.com/how-to/change-pitch-formant-your-voice-with-audacity-335544/

Comment: Vocoder usually can achieve somewhat decent results but there is a learning curve.

Comment: @ToddWilcox Woa! Just what I wanted. I actually working on the VST plugin atm, I wonder there exist plugin with that functionanility!. Formant of a voice.. got it. Wil check that

Answer (score 1):

You may have a look at Melodyne. I've never used it though.